# Send emails via CURL (shell script) CURL command returned 0 but the receiver didn't receive the attached files but the message

Tags: shell, email, unix, curl

I've run into a problem with sending emails via CURL using shell script.

I have a script that do:

1. Download dashboards from our Tableau server (private) via tabcmd command then save these files into a directory.
2. Send these files to receivers using a SMTP sever (private) via CURL. Both Tableau Server and SMTP server are installed on a container CENTOS 7. I have CURL version 7.29.

I have a list of dashboards and list of emails. For each dashboard (that has a unique URL), the script downloads the dashboard files and then send the files to receiver.

**My problem is that for some receivers they received their attached files but others didn't**. I checked the stdout of CURL command, it returned that

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to services.xxxx.xx.xxxx.xxx port 25 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx...
* Connected to services.xxxx.xx.xxxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 25 (#0)
< 220 xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx ESMTP Postfix
> EHLO tableau
< xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-SIZE 10240000
< 250-VRFY
< 250-ETRN
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-DSN
< 250-SMTPUTF8
< 250 CHUNKING
> MAIL FROM:<xxxxx@yyyy.email.com>
< 250 2.1.0 Ok
> RCPT TO:<xxxx@yyyy.hotmail.com>
< 250 2.1.5 Ok
> DATA
< 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
} [data not shown]
< 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2xxxxx

  0     0    0     0    0  130k      0  5735k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5932k
* Connection #0 to host services.xxxx.xx.xxxx.xxx left intact
```

**This means that the email is sent successfully with attached files. But the receiver didn't receive the attached files**. I also checked that the files were in the directory.

The code to send email is something like that:

```
send_pdf(){
   
    receiver="$1"
    subject="$2"
    message="$3"
    num_file_attaches=$(expr $# - 3)

    eval body=$(cat parameters/data.txt)

    for file in "${@:4}"; do
        add_file "$body" "$file"
    done

    body+="--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY--"
    echo -e "$body" | curl -s "$SMTP_SERVER" \
        --mail-from "$SENDER" \
        --mail-rcpt "$receiver"\
        -T -

}
```

and the function **add_file**

```
add_file() {
    body="$1"
    file_attach="$2"
    name_file_attach=$(basename $file_attach)
    file_base64=$(cat $file_attach | base64)

    MIMEType=`file --mime-type "$file_attach" | sed 's/.*: //'`
    body+="--MULTIPART-MIXED-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: $MIMEType;name=${name_file_attach}\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nContent-Disposition: attachment;filename=${name_file_attach}\n\n\n${file_base64}\n\n\n"
}
```

For each time I test with my emails, the script works but when I replace my email by those of clients, there are always some clients who didn't receive attached files. However, these clients received the message.

I can't do some tests with emails of clients :( So, I can't reproduce the problem.

**Does anyone have any idea where the problem could come from or how can I reproduce the problem?**

Many thanks,

Comment: Basically, the root cause could be a security component on receiver side that disable the attached files in mail?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I send email to a receiver named A three times. The first time with files x1, x2, x3, the receiver received the attached files. The second time with files y1, y2, y3, he received all files. But the third time with z1,z2, z3 he didn't receive these files. Do you also think that the cause could be a security component ?

Comment: Really strange, the size of files are the same each time or something change (extension of the file could impact too).

Comment: Because attached files are different for each sending time, so the size of files are different but the files are small. I just attached some pdf files. And the client emails have the same domain.